# Script that will get EXACT name or character

Tags: shell, scripting

For example

I need to get “ABC” value in File1

File1 contains:

```
ABC
ABC
ABCD
ABCDE
```

Comment: What is your desired output? Just the first two lines? i.e. `grep -x ABC File1`?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
grep '/^ABC$/' file.in
```

or

```
grep -x 'ABC' file.in
```

if you want the match to occur on a line by itself.

Use

```
grep -w 'ABC' file.in
```

to match the *word* `ABC` (i.e. the string `ABC` surrounded by non-alphanumeric characters, or start/end of line).  This would match a line containing e.g. `123 ABC 123`.

In addition, use `-F` if `ABC` is not a regular expression but a static string. And use `-o` if you want `grep` to return *only* the matched strings and not the whole line containing the match.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the two values returned:

`grep -ow ABC File1`

> -o, --only-matching
>   Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
>
> -w, --word-regexp
>   Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.